# Disable one on page form when the other form has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

So I have a problem where I have two forms with the same ID on the same web page (assume I can't change the ID very easily for either form and both forms are required on the page).

When I submit one of the forms, it is also submitting the other form, blank, creating two submissions.

I would like to disable the opposite form of the form with current focus.  So for example, if the submit button of the form at the bottom of the page is submitting, then ideally the top form would already be disabled with javascript and eliminate the second submission.

Here is the code for the top form -

```
<div id="gf_top">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="gform_1" action="/">
```

And the bottom form -

```
<div id="gf_bottom">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="gform_1" action="/">
```

I know zero javascript / JQuery.

I suspect I need to use something like (based on some google searches)

```
$("#gf_top #gform1 :input").attr('disabled', true);
```

but I don't really know the code to add for the focus of one disables the other. I guess also there needs to be code to remove the disabled attribute when/if the disabled form receives focus and then disable the other...  Sheesh, any help much appreciated!

Comment: "So I have a problem where I have two forms with the same ID on the same web page"... Indeed you have a problem

Comment: You **can't** have two elements with the same id.

Comment: Well ofcourse you can, but you shouldn't. Have you tried changing the id thru jquery? `$('#gf_top > form').attr('id', 'newid')` don't know if that works, but it fixes multiple issues if it does.

Answer (score 2):

You **can't** (shouldn't) have two elements with the same id. **Change an id**.

To get the forms without id you can use its tag name:

```
// All inputs of gf_top form are disabled
$("#gf_top form input").attr('disabled', true);
```

[W3 says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) about the `id` attribute:

> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

Answer (score 0):

You will at least try to get rid of those ids if you can't give your forms their own one. And you have to do this before the html is rendered (server side).

Once you get there, you don't have to worry about disabling anything. Only the form where the submit button is pressed will be sent.